# Iterate into an array of hash

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, each

I'm trying to loop into an array of hash :

```
response = [
  {
    "element" => A,
    "group" => {"created" => 13, "code" => "Paris.rb", :"rsvp_limit" => 40},
    "name" => "CODELAB",
    "venue" => {"id" => 17485302, "place" => "la cordée", "visibility" => "public"}
  },
  {
    "element" => B,
    "group" => {"created" => 13, "code" => "Paris.rb", :"rsvp_limit" => 40},
    "name" => "PARISRB",
    "venue" => {"id" => 17485302, "place" => "la cordée", "visibility" => "public"}
  }
]
```

When I run

- `response[0]["name"]`, it returns `"CODELAB"`
- `response[1]["name"]` returns `"PARISRB"`

How can I make a loop to have the name of each element of this array of hash ?

I tried :

```
response.each_with_index do |resp, index|
  puts array[index]["name"]
end
```

This is the error I get in my console :

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
from (pry):58:in `block in __pry__'
```

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `array` here seems to be a typo. You meant:

```
response.each_with_index do |resp, index|
  puts resp["name"]
end
```

The index is not needed because the `resp` variable is correctly initialized to contain the hash at each iteration.

So it can be simplified to:

```
response.each do |resp|
  puts resp["name"]
end
```

Comment: If the answer was useful to you, @Ludivinecp, then accept it. This way you help those who helped you.

Answer (score 3):

A little bit shorter:

```
puts response.map{|hash| hash['name']}
# CODELAB
# PARISRB
```